Is there a Basecamp API that shows each time a card was moved to a different column?
In the Basecamp UI, I can see each time a card was moved to a different column, along with the date of the move.
I am not finding an API that shows that same information.  Does this kind of API exist?
I have already searched the API documentation on Github, but API documentation is not always intuitive.  I also asked my question direction to Basecamp support, and they directed me here.

I have found my own answer.  There is a recordings/event API that looks like this:
buckets/1/recordings/2/events.json, where '1' is the bucket id, and '2' is the card id.  In the returned JSON data, there is a field called 'action' - look for a value of 'adopted'.  Under 'details', there are 2 fields called 'new_parent_id' and 'parent_id_was' - these refer to the column ids.
Reading this data will tell you when and where a card was moved to a different column.
